# Is sending my token in Authorization header any better than sending it in POST body?

Tags: python, http, post, get, python-requests

I'm creating a RESTful api.

Currently I send requests in a POST body:

```
data = {
    'token': token,
    'some-data': some_data
}
return requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api/endpoint', data)
```

My question is would it be better if I sent token in Authorization header?

Something like this:

```
data = {
    'some-data':some_data
}
return requests.post('http://localhost:5000/api/endpoint', data, headers=('Authorization: Bearer:%s' % token)
```

Comment: It's not about what is better. If you are not using ssl, headers or post body run over network in plain text. You need means of authentication/authorization also for GET requests. But imho it's better in headers because if your auth data will always be part of post body they will mingle with other data you want to send.

Comment: @beezz I see. What do you mean by mingle with other data though?

Comment: I mean cases where you want to send also something else besides your auth data. Like creating some resource. Then you will have to remove your auth data before passing post body to create function. Or when you will be creating validating schema for some views you will have to think about the auth data all the time.